# Why I cant use v2 Google recaptcha key for the invisible recaptcha key?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have several websites having v2 Google Recaptcha and now I want to upgrade it to Invisible Recaptcha.
While implementing found that:
current keys (site key and secret key) will not work for the invisible recaptcha implementation.

What is the flexible solution for this?
How we can use the existing keys ( v2 ) for the invisible recaptcha?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't - you need to get new keys for the Invisible Recaptcha. You can get them at:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Assuming you have a Google account.